# Difference of Point in Polygon and Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: collision-detection

So I need to get a boolean, true or false if two, complex polygons intersects.

The Separating Axis Theorem does only support convex polygons which is then not what I need.

I've heard of Polygon Clipping, but really, if you use an the algorithm to check if a point is inside a polygon can't you just to like this:

```
if ( any point of A's points are inside B OR any point of B's points are inside A )
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You need to check for side's collisions too at least.

[image: this is why]

Comment: Wow, never thought of that.

Comment: @Murplyx If this is for some physics engine, you might get way with checking the points only, especially if the changes from frame to frame are small. In the general case, the problem becomes quite hard to compute unfortunately.